# Change Ownership of a file in Racket

Tags: file, scripting, system, racket

Is there anyway I can modify the ownership of a file in Racket. I know I could theoretically use [`system*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html?q=system*#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._system%2A%29%29) to execute `chown` (or a Windows equivalent), but I'd like to use a primitive built into Racket if one exists.

Something like [`file-or-directory-permissions`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=file-permission#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._file-or-directory-permissions%29%29) would be nice, except for ownership. (Say `file-or-directory-owner`?)

Comment: Look at [FFI implementation](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/synx/util.plt/2/0/permissions.rkt)

Answer (score 0):

The Racket has not something like file-or-directory-permissions.
I know two ways to do this:

1. [Subprocess](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#(part._.Simple_.Subprocesses)
2. [FFI implementation](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/synx/util.plt/2/0/permissions.rkt)